# jquery function doesn't work on element that write through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have some jQuery code like this :

```
$(function($) {
$('input.autonumeric').autoNumeric({aSep: ',', aDec: '.',vMax:'1000000000000'}); });
```

with that code, every input text that have `autonumeric`-class can only input with numeric.

but when i write input text tag from `innerHTML`, it doesn't work at all. this is how i write the code :

```
function edit(){
  var current = window.event.srcElement;
  while ( (current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName !="TR");
  var row = current.childNodes;
  td = row.item(0); var temp = td.innerHTML;
  td.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+temp+"\" class=\"autonumeric\" \>";
}
```

how can i solve this code? note: i'm sorry if my english not good enough.

Comment: Does your code even outputs more than one text input? You have a semicolon after the `while` statement. And even if you take out the semicolon, only the `var row = current.childNodes;` line would be looped as you're not using curly braces `{}` after your `while` statement.

Comment: i not sure about it. that "while" line of code i got from other blog. but i thinks, that line means "make the "current" variable to the 'tr' tag position. so, that "current = current.parentElement" code inside "while" changes the content of "current" variable too..

Comment: Oh yes never mind. Didn't realize there was an `=` inside the while loop. The first part always returns true while the second warrants that the loop will be repeated until the current element's tagName is differently than `TR`. It could be done in a tidier/cleaner way, but can work like that.

Comment: Now that I took another look, that's an effective non-jQuery way to grab the parent `<tr>` element of the event's target. Since you're using jQuery, that `while` loop would be the same as `current = $(current).parents('tr')[0];` - just for future reference. `:)` There's no need to rewrite the code if it's working.

Comment: hei... it's work... great!!! but i still don't understands why we add "[0]" in "current = $(current).parents('tr')[0];" ???

Comment: it's simple - `$(current).parents('tr')` returns a jQuery object containing the parent `tr` element. Your function is written in pure JS, which requires DOM elements to work with, not jQuery objects. Hence, when you add `[0]`, which is a shorthand for [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), it returns the first (and only) matched element inside the jQuery object as a DOM element which is usable by your function. `=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to run autoNumeric for the newly added Elements as well.
You could do it right at the creation of the new input like that:

```
$(td).html($("<input type=\"text\" value=\""+temp+"\" class=\"autonumeric\" \>").autoNumeric({'....'}));
```

or leave your version and run

```
$('input.autonumeric').autoNumeric({aSep: ',', aDec: '.',vMax:'1000000000000'}); });
```

again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery why don't you create the element with jQuery?

```
var e = $('<input type="text" />');
e.autoNumeric({aSep: ',', aDec: '.',vMax:'1000000000000'}); });
td.html(e);
```

Of course you need to adjust the other part of the code to make sure td is a jQuery object.

Comment: This doesn't create a jQuery object though. `e`  is just a string in your case, and will throw an error since string has no method `autoNumeric`

Comment: True, forgot $() around the string.

Answer (score 0):

When the jQuery plugin method `.autoNumeric(...)` is run, it affects all input fields *currently present* in the DOM. When `edit()` is invoked and a new `input.autonumeric` is created, you have to call `.autonumeric(...)` again.

Answer (score 0):

After you add the innerHTML you should make a call to your autoNumeric function again. This is because the code executed at page load can only 'see' the elements present in the DOM at page load. Once you add the element you will have to attach your events to it.

Comment: how about css, is there need to be reloaded to get the css effect too?

Comment: No, css (from an external stylesheet, or from a style element) is applied when an element is shown. Of course if you add css to elements with javascript on page load (inline style, for example `$("span").css("color","red");`) and after that you add an element your newly added element will not have this style until you apply it programmatically.